# Angular Build error: Unknown version 64 of op_mob

Tags: angular, jenkins, build

I am facing the following error when Jenkins try to build my angular application.
In my dev environment it builds correctly without no error.

```
./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
HookWebpackError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/babel/webpack-loader.js):
BrowserslistError: [BABEL] /usr/src/app/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/css-loader/dist/runtime/sourceMaps.js: Unknown version 64 of op_mob (While processing: "base$0$0")

 

./src/styles.css - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
HookWebpackError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/babel/webpack-loader.js):
BrowserslistError: [BABEL] /usr/src/app/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/css-loader/dist/runtime/sourceMaps.js: Unknown version 64 of op_mob (While processing: "base$0$0")

 

./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/css-loader/dist/runtime/api.js - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/babel/webpack-loader.js):
BrowserslistError: [BABEL] /usr/src/app/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/css-loader/dist/runtime/api.js: Unknown version 64 of op_mob (While processing: "base$0$0")

 

./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/css-loader/dist/runtime/sourceMaps.js - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/babel/webpack-loader.js):
BrowserslistError: [BABEL] /usr/src/app/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/css-loader/dist/runtime/sourceMaps.js: Unknown version 64 of op_mob (While processing: "base$0$0")

 

./node_modules/@angular/cdk/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/collections.js - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/babel/webpack-loader.js):
BrowserslistError: [BABEL] /usr/src/app/node_modules/@angular/cdk/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/collections.js: Unknown version 64 of op_mob (While processing: "base$0$0")

.....
   


./node_modules/keycloak-angular/fesm2015/keycloak-angular.mjs - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/babel/webpack-loader.js):
BrowserslistError: [BABEL] /usr/src/app/node_modules/keycloak-angular/fesm2015/keycloak-angular.mjs: Unknown version 64 of op_mob (While processing: "base$0$0")
```

Any idea?